# In ngIf need to return a boolean from object value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In ngIf need to return a boolean from object value.

`var a = {"c" : "b","f": "g"}`

a["c"] => 'b'

(a && a["c"]) =>  'b' // why here it is not returning true

a && a["c"]  =>  'b' // How to return a boolean from a value here

!!( a && a["c"]) => true // is it correct way to return true or any other better way available?

`<button title="Submit" *ngIf="!!(a && a["c"])">Submit</button>`

Comment: Any condition in `*ngIf` converts to boolean automatically, you don't need to do it manually, both `a["c"]` and `a && a["c"]` are correct.

Comment: `(a && a["c"])` returns `a` if `a` is falsy and `a["c"]` if `a` is truthy. An object is always truthy, therefore `(a && a["c"])` returns `"b"`. `!!` is a common operation to convert a truthy value to true and a falsy value to false. I would use `!!(a && a["c"])` to convert `(a && a["c"])` to boolean. You can make it shorter with `!!a?.c`.

Comment: (a && a["c"]) => 'b' ... (a) && (a["c"]  => 'b') - you have bracket precedence issues

Comment: @JGFMK I don't think `(a && a["c"]) => 'b'` is actual code. The code is `(a && a["c"])` and `'b'` is the result. Your recommendation `a["c"] => 'b'` isn't even valid JavaScript.

Comment: a is saying 'a' exists. a["c"], takes the value of the contents - b and says is it greater than or equal to b - which it would be - you can't do a logical or on truth and a character - and compare it to a character literal - so I am correct.

Comment: @JGFMK Of course, you can. Try `console.log({"c" : "b","f": "g"} && 'b')`. The output is `'b'`.

Comment: @JGFMK You can also try `console.log({"c" : "b","f": "g"} || 'b')` and the output is `{"c" : "b","f": "g"}`. Neither `{"c" : "b","f": "g"}` nor `'b'` is converted or coerced to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

*"why here it is not returning true"*

`(a && a["c"])` returns `a` if `a` is falsy and `a["c"]` if `a` is truthy. An object is always truthy, therefore `(a && a["c"])` returns `"b"`.

*"How to return a boolean from a value here"*

`!!` is a common operation to convert a truthy value to true and a falsy value to false.

*"is it correct way to return true or any other better way available?"*

It is correct and I would use `!!(a && a["c"])` to convert `(a && a["c"])` to boolean.

You can make it shorter with `!!a?.c` ([optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)):

```
<button title="Submit" *ngIf="!!a?.c">Submit</button>
```

or even

```
<button title="Submit" *ngIf="a?.c">Submit</button>
```

if your TypeScript configuration allows it.

I recommend to check the list of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. Sometimes the results can be very surprising.